# I can not connect to ssh server

Tags: linux, ssh, server, client, yocto

I would be very glad for some advice.
Hello guys I have Linux development board, which runs ssh-server-dropbear. Then the board is connected via ethernet cord into our local network(into router). Command "ip a" works. I installed open-ssh on my ubuntu 16.04. I'm using VMware simulator on windows 10 computer. When I try to ssh into the board from ubuntu with command: ssh root@192.168.30.202 the command is running, but I can not connect. The output is:

"ssh: connect to host 192.168.30.202 port 22: Connection refused"

Can someone know why it could be a problem? I tried this on 2 computers.
One was laptop and second is full pc. I was thinking that it could be, because the VMware workstation, but I tried all types of network setting and it's still same.

I is development board http://www.myirtech.com/list.asp?id=573 .
I have windows 10 and on in VMWorkstation with Ubuntu.

**SSH SERVER**

```
root@myd-y6ull14x14:~# ssh
Dropbear SSH client v2019.78 https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html
Usage: ssh [options] [user@]host[/port][,[user@]host/port],...] [command]
-p <remoteport>
-l <username>
-t    Allocate a pty
-T    Don't allocate a pty
-N    Don't run a remote command
-f    Run in background after auth
-y    Always accept remote host key if unknown
-y -y Don't perform any remote host key checking (caution)
-s    Request a subsystem (use by external sftp)
-o option     Set option in OpenSSH-like format ('-o help' to list options)
-i <identityfile>   (multiple allowed, default .ssh/id_dropbear)
-A    Enable agent auth forwarding
-L <[listenaddress:]listenport:remotehost:remoteport> Local port forwarding
-g    Allow remote hosts to connect to forwarded ports
-R <[listenaddress:]listenport:remotehost:remoteport> Remote port forwarding
-W <receive_window_buffer> (default 24576, larger may be faster, max 1MB)
-K <keepalive>  (0 is never, default 0)
-I <idle_timeout>  (0 is never, default 0)
-B <endhost:endport> Netcat-alike forwarding
-J <proxy_program> Use program pipe rather than TCP connection
-c <cipher list> Specify preferred ciphers ('-c help' to list options)
-m <MAC list> Specify preferred MACs for packet verification (or '-m help')
-b    [bind_address][:bind_port]
-V    Version
```

**ip a**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: can0: <NOARP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 10
    link/can 
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:df:74:e2:6f:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.30.202/24 brd 192.168.30.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8df:74ff:fee2:6f39/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ee:e1:a2:03:a9:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: What's that topology again? The "board" sounds like a physical device (since it's "plugged in" somewhere). Where do Windows 10 and VMware and Ubuntu factor in? Is Ubuntu a VM running on a Win10 host? If so, please try the shortest route first and find out if the "board" is reachable via the host (use PuTTY or sth. like that), then dive deeper.

Comment: So I tried it. Into ip I typed: 192.168.30.202. It said connection timed out.

Comment: No, man. That wasn't an answer. Could you clarify your setup, please? Use the questions in my previous comment to augment your question. That makes it easier to _actually_ answer it. In _your_ last comment you kinda neglected to indicate from where you "typed an IP address".

Please, try to switch roles here. With _that_ little information, would you be able to form a definitive answer if you'd been asked the question? Provide as much info as you can.

Comment: Sorry, I was on windows trying to connect via putty.  The ip which I was connecting was 192.168.30.202; Port 22; Telnet How it should be. I added the board into the question text. Basically I can not connect to it through out windows. It is shorter route.

Comment: The local "board" (let's call it a server from now on, maybe?): does it have sshd running? What does `netstat -lnp|grep ssh` tell you when you run it on that server?

Comment: root@myd-y6ull14x14:~# netstat -lnp | grep ssh
netstat: invalid option -- 'p'
BusyBox v1.31.0 (2022-08-03 14:54:38 UTC) multi-call binary.

Comment: BusyBox? That doesn't sound like a server at all.

Comment: Really, but this should work. What this means ? In document of the board is that it can do ssh server and ssh command shows, that it is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my windows DNS setting, in past I set the DNS to manuall, after I switch the setting back to automatic the ssh connection works, how it should.